Delete lines containing partial string match
I have 2 files
file1
00:00:00:00:00:01

file2
00:00:00:00:00:02 foo bar
00:00:00:00:00:01 something else

What I want to do is compare the two files and remove 00:00:00:00:00:01 from file 2 so I end up with
file 2
00:00:00:00:00:02 foo bar

I tried
grep -Fvx file1 file2

But it doesn't appear to work for partial line matches.

Why should be the 02 line removed, byt the 01 line should not?

Please explain the logic you want help with. How can we know which line to remove? And what partial line matches? Your example doesn't have any, so if your real data do, please show us an example that reflects that so we can give you what you need.

I guess you're looking for grep -Fv -f file1 file2. that should work as long as the strings in file1 cannot match anything other than the whole first field of file2

awk '
  ! file1_processed {file1[$0]; next}
  ! ($1 in file1)' file1 file1_processed=1 file2

Would output the lines of file2 where the first field ($1) is not found as a line ($0) in file1.
The -x in grep -Fvxf file1 file2 (you forgot the -f btw) is for exact match, so that would remove the lines of file2 that are exactly any one of the lines of file1.
If you remove that -x:
grep -Fvf file1 file2

Then that removes the lines of file2 that contain any of the lines of file1, so that would remove the 00:00:00:00:00:01 something else line but, contrary to the awk approach above, also a line such as 00:00:00:00:00:02 whatever00:00:00:00:00:01:02:03.
